# How to Render Google Play Music in my custom fragment on Android

Tags: android

Actually I got the `Intent` for Google Play Music to directly call it from Fragment. And it will open the Google Play Music Activity. 
But I want to open the player in my_fragment which is a part of an `Activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Fragments are no iframes.

An intent just tells the Android system "Hey, I want to run the music player", and if Android finds any app that has registered itself to be able to handle that intent, that app is started.